# Non-blocking queue in Java using AtomicStampedReference

Tags: java, concurrency

So I'll start by saying this is for an assignment, and there are a few restrictions on the queue I need to build:

1. It is unbounded.
2. No locking mechanisms are allowed(no `synchronized`, `ReentrantLock`, etc){not even to simulate things like CompareAndSet}.
3. It must implement [Michael and Scott's](http://www.research.ibm.com/people/m/michael/podc-1996.pdf) algorithm.
4. Of course, I can't rip off Java's source code for `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`.

Here's what I have so far(dequeue is left out):

```
public class LockFreeQueue<T> implements MyQueue<T>
{
    private class Node<R>
    {
        public final R value;
        public volatile AtomicReference<Node<R>> next;

        public Node()
        {
            value = null;
            next = new AtomicReference<Node<R>>(null);
        }

        public Node(R v)
        {
            value = v;
            next = new AtomicReference<Node<R>>(null);
        }
    }

    volatile AtomicStampedReference<Node<T>> head = new AtomicStampedReference<Node<T>>(new Node<T>(), 0);
    volatile AtomicStampedReference<Node<T>> tail = head;
    AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);

    public boolean enq(T value)
    {
        Node<T> node = new Node<T>(value);

        while (true)
        {
            Node<T> tempTail = tail.getReference();
            int tailCount = tail.getStamp();
            Node<T> next = tempTail.next.get();
            if (tempTail == tail.getReference())
            {
                if (null == next)
                {
                    if(tempTail.next.compareAndSet(null, node))
                    {
                        // Problem on this line:
                        tail.compareAndSet(tempTail, node, tailCount, count.incrementAndGet());
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    tail.compareAndSet(tempTail, next, tailCount, count.incrementAndGet());
                }
            }
        }
    }
...
}
```

Now, for the most part, this follows the code found in [this IBM article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp04186/).  Particularly, it follows the code in `Listing 4. Insertion in the Michael-Scott nonblocking queue algorithm`.  The problem, which is exhibited by both my code and the code in the article, is that when the reference for the tail is swung to the new tail, it does the same for the head. It does this of course because it's changing the `Node` being referred to, rather than the actual reference, and the reference that `tail` and `head` have are the same.

I also found [a different solution](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/classes/EDU/oswego/cs/dl/util/concurrent/WaitFreeQueue.java) but the main problem with this code is that it uses `synchronized`, even though it's only doing so to simulate a CAS operation.

As far as Java's [`ConcurrentLinkedQueue`](http://fuseyism.com/classpath/doc/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue-source.html) goes, I've noticed that they utilize [`AtomicReferenceUpdater`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater.html) and that really seems to be the only way to go.  The problem here, though, is that my code starts to look surprisingly close to Java's and I don't want to be docked points for plagiarism(or worse!).

Is `AtomicReferenceUpdater` the only way for me to move forward, or are there other things I can do?

A last note:

- `Node` is a total fabrication of my own, so it can change to be anything it needs to be.

**Edit:**

Ben Manes mentioned not needing to be concerned about the ABA problem in a language with garbage collection.  For those interested in this in the future, there's [this article](http://www.hergert.me/blog/2009/12/25/intro-to-lock-free-wait-free-and-aba.html) which is a nice read.  The important part:

> In garbage collected languages this isn't a problem. Why? Because the node's memory cannot be reclaimed for a new object until observing threads containing pointers to the structure have released them.

Comment: You can get rid of the counter as that seems to be for the ABA problem, which won't be an issue due to Java's GC. That should simplify it to be more like Java's CLQ.

Comment: @BenManes Thanks for that tip.  I hadn't considered the effects of a GC on the ABA problem.  I found an article that explains that in a short, sweet fashion so I'll edit it in.

Comment: `AtomicReferenceUpdater` does not offer anything which you can’t do as well with an `AtomicReference`. It only reduces the per-field storage requirement as you have one `static` updater instead of one atomic reference object per instance. But I have no idea how the *stamped* reference comes into play. What do you want to do with the stamp?

Comment: @Holger I think at this point I can ignore the stamp and just use an `AtomicReference`.  In fact, I've tried the above with the necessary alterations between the two, but I still have the same issue where updating `tail` will update `head`(since CAS changes the node inside the reference, not the reference itself).

Comment: Well, the only cure is to modify the `tail` field so it doesn’t point to the same object as the head anymore. I guess, at one time you will have to change the `head` as well. But as said, you don’t need an `AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater` for that. You could also change the type of the `head` and `tail` fields to `AtomicReference<Node<E>>` instead. If you want to avoid being too similar to the JRE version, that’s the way to go. Any it would be strange to use `AtomicReference`s in the nodes and `AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater`s in the queue class, as there are much more nodes than queues…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not CAS, it's aliasing.

As you well said, CAS doesn't change the reference, it changes what the reference points to.

If the tail reference was pointing to tempTail it will now point to node. And that's great, but since head was sharing this reference as well it will also be pointing to node.

So when you do:

```
tail.compareAndSet(tempTail, node, tailCount, count.incrementAndGet());
```

You're going from this:
[image]

To this:
[image]

So your problem started before, when you created one reference for both variables instead of two separate references pointing to the same object.

So when you did:

```
volatile AtomicStampedReference<Node<T>> head = new AtomicStampedReference<Node<T>>(new Node<T>(), 0);
volatile AtomicStampedReference<Node<T>> tail = head;
```

You created this scenario:
[image]

Instead, you should've created this scenario:
[image]

And you can do it with this code:

```
Node<T> centinell = new Node<T>();
head = new AtomicStampedReference<Node<T>>(centinell, 0);
tail = new AtomicStampedReference<Node<T>>(centinell, 0);
```

Also, you can change all the AtomicStampedReference for AtomicReference and it will work all the same.